# How to Save Object of Maven Libraries Using Hibernate JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, bloom-filter

I am implementing Bloom Filter in a maven project using

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Where we create an object like

```
BloomFilter<String> names = BloomFilter.create(Funnels.stringFunnel(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), 10000,0.005);
```

I wanted to know if there is any way to save object from maven libraries in Hibernate. In this case, can we save the object "names" using Hibernate?

Comment: What do you want to save? In the Filter you have set of Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stored them as BLOB objects.